# Compare object properties in 2 lists

Tags: c#, list, compare

I found, in some other questions, information on how to compare two lists of objects and get the difference in the sense that objects in lists are different. 
I am not sure if the same/similar thing is possible in the case that I have the same objects in two lists, but with possibly different property values of particular objects in two lists.

Is there a shortcut to check for that case?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand your question correctly but you could override the `Equals` method of the objects stored in the list and than compare it with that method. With this approach you can define if objects are equal or not yourself.

Comment: An example of some typical input and the desired output resulting from that would make this a lot clearer. Your description is a bit fuzzy. I would guess this is perfectly possible but it's not obvious what precise situation or data structure you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is described on [this page:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

**Example** (*copied from the above linked MSDN site* to keep the answer on StackOverflow):

```
// This class defines your objects with your properties.
public class ProductA
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}

// This class is used for custom comparison.
public class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<ProductA>
{

    public bool Equals(ProductA x, ProductA y)
    {
        //Check whether the objects are the same object. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal. 
        return x != null && y != null && x.Code.Equals(y.Code) && x.Name.Equals(y.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ProductA obj)
    {
        int hashProductName = obj.Name == null ? 0 : obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        int hashProductCode = obj.Code.GetHashCode();
        return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
    }
}
```

Here is how you could use that now:

```
ProductA[] fruits1 = { new ProductA { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                   new ProductA { Name = "orange", Code = 4 },
                    new ProductA { Name = "lemon", Code = 12 } };

ProductA[] fruits2 = { new ProductA { Name = "apple", Code = 9 } };

// Get all the elements from the first array except for the elements from the second array.    
IEnumerable<ProductA> except = fruits1.Except(fruits2);
```